# Finding or monitoring construction projects with GIS

Tags: data

How can we as an organization use GIS to monitor construction projects in the country, to be able to search for and identify construction taking place?

This is in order to be able to visit the various sites to ensure construction projects are registered and being built according to regulations. We are unable to manually go all over, and as a result illegal buildings are coming up that are eventually collapsing and costing lives.

Comment: i think that this problem is related to governemental urban administrations which has the role to regulate constructions, not to construction companies.

Comment: Why did you tag this with "raster", when this has nothing to do with raster datatypes?  As it stands, I think this question is far too broad.  You may need to do some research outside of GIS SE, and come back with a focused, specific question.

Comment: GIS is not something that automatically populates itself with data -- you will need to know where the construction is happening, and enter that into your GIS system yourself to keep track of it. It would be possible to figure out an optimal route for visiting construction sites to check, and track which have (or haven't) been visited -- however, it cannot be used to _discover_ construction sites for you.

Comment: There are various approaches you can use but a lot will depend on the nature of the construction site data. What means do you have of identifying construction sites?  I assume planning applications are only useful to a certain extent if you are wanting to identify illegal construction.

Comment: It does sound like you will need to construct some cadastral system for your purpose.